Bridge rectifier in telephone speech circuit
In the IC TEA1062, I am unable to understand the path of the signals when bridge rectifier is placed on line interface. Especially when speech signals are output from the pin no.1. Would it not block the output? Can someone please explain how the bridge rectifier works in this case or in general with speech.
Edit : The diodes are foward biased when coming in to the Ic. There is positive voltage with respect to ground on pin 1 LN =9v. If I feed 1khz signal on the mic input. I can see it on this pin biased with this dc voltage which is provided by the - 48v source. Same signal is visible on the telephone line side of the the bridge rectifier.

Image source: Page 20 of this TEA1062 datasheet on alldatasheet.com

You should read page 7 of datasheet (sidetone suppression).
